# анимация только один раз

Tags: jquery, animate

Каждый раз когда скролю, анимация проигрывается каждый раз. Как сделать чтоб только раз?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(st);
    if(st >= 500 && st<=1100){
        $('#nume_1').animateNumber({number: 84});
        $('#nume_2').animateNumber({number: 75});
        $('#nume_3').animateNumber({number: 4});
        $('#sp3').animateNumber({number: 5});
        $('#nume_4').animateNumber({number: 29});
        $('#nume_5').animateNumber({number: 5});
        $('#nume_6').animateNumber({number: 400});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var scrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (!scrolled) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(st);
        if(st >= 500 && st<=1100){
            scrolled = true;
            $('#nume_1').animateNumber({number: 84});
            $('#nume_2').animateNumber({number: 75});
            $('#nume_3').animateNumber({number: 4});
            $('#sp3').animateNumber({number: 5});
            $('#nume_4').animateNumber({number: 29});
            $('#nume_5').animateNumber({number: 5});
            $('#nume_6').animateNumber({number: 400});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо. Работает

Comment: а не проще метод one `.one('scroll', function(){})` ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude и? сработает на один факт скрола, а не на запуск цифр